# Aggregate a data frame in R using multiple FUN (mean, min, SD)

Tags: r

I am trying to aggregate a data frame to find the mean, min, and SD of a specific column compared to another. I would like to aggregate Semester, and only apply mean, SD, and min to Grade. Then display all in one output as columns (aggregated-Semester, mean, min, SD). Is this possible? Below is the example data frame.

(Sorry for output of data frame, not sure how to create a table in the questions)

```
#------------------------------------------
#|Student   |Semester   |Grade  |Name    |
#------------------------------------------
#|1         |9a         |90     |Jim     |
#|2         |9b         |91     |Beth    |
#|3         |9a         |76     |George  |
#|4         |9b         |87     |Phill   |
#------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Mean = mean(Grade), Max = max(Grade), SD = sd(Grade)), by = Semester]
```

---

Or with `aggregate`

```
f1 <- function(x) c(Mean = mean(x), Max = max(x), SD = sd(x))
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(Grade~Semester, df, f1))
```

Comment: The aggregate option works great! THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one example:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="
Student   Semester   Grade  Name    
1         9a         90     Jim     
2         9b         91     Beth    
3         9a         76     George  
4         9b         87     Phill")
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Semester) %>% summarise_at(vars(Grade), funs(mean, max, sd))
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Semester  mean   max       sd
#     <fctr> <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
# 1       9a    83    90 9.899495
# 2       9b    89    91 2.828427
```